# captivate 7 does not run the exe on windows xp

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

We are using adobe captivate 7 installed (trail version ) in a windows 7 with SP1 computer . when we publish it and run exe in the windows XP (home ) under administrator we get  following error even if the flash player is updated.

```
The installed version of Flash Player is not the latest.  The latest Flash Player version has been installed successfully without affecting your existing Flash Player installation.  Double-click the EXE again to run it.
```

when we click OK it disappears and when we run the exe for the next time it runs . whereas if we run the same exe in the other user (not having admin permission ) also gets the same error and after clicking OK if we run exe again it shows the same error message again and again .

we have tested in win 7, win 8 , win server 2012 it works fine.

Please suggest me how to prevent it .

Comment: Simplest answer - throw away XP. It's not supported any more, by anybody.

Comment: @Tetsujin There are so many customers who use XP.

Comment: the error sometimes occurs in win 7 also